# Last coma is not getting removed

Tags: c#

I am creating a query at run time , it is a really long query 
I have to remove coma from last which is causing error in executing this .
I followed two approach

```
  string final_query = query.ToString();
  final_query = final_query.Substring(0, final_query.Length - 1);
```

And Second

```
   string final_query = query.ToString();
   final_query = final_query.TrimEnd(',');
```

A little part of final query is this (this is how I am creating this query and it is in loop)

```
 query.Append(" ('" + state + "', 'Y', 'Division Name',' ', '" + state + "',  GETDATE(), 'Summary', '', 'Business Report', ' ', ' '),");
```

Both TrimEnd and substring should remove the last comma but they are doing nothing here , Can somebody tell me why is this behaviour . I am using VS 2010

Comment: Seems like `query` is a stringbuilder object, so Can you please share more code where and how you are using Trim?

Comment: @un-lucky , its already there , please see  first two code formatted lines

Comment: @Saurabh provide full code with the loop and part where you use `TrimEnd`

Comment: Are you sure you don't have space at the end?

Comment: Funny typo - don't we all want the last coma to be removed?

Comment: @TaW high five....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove from last index of the comma like this:

```
string a ="asda,aasdas,asd,asd,";
var res = a.Remove(a.LastIndexOf(','));

Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Comment: I have the same question , does TrimEnd does not apply to string converted from StringBuilder ?

Comment: @un-lucky TrimEnd won't work if he has spaces or anything else after comma

Comment: @un-lucky yes, but this is only one line from his loop and while he has not provided full code we can't say for sure why it's not working

Comment: @un-lucky also I can say that if his substring is not woking for him it's showing that the comma is not the last symbol in string

Comment: @un-lucky , for your curiosity , it is already mentioned that "it is a really long query " , almost 70 lines even after looping , I appreciate your concern but enough details are given here already , S.Petrosov got it very quick , I am sorry if you feel it in-complete Information but posting that much code is inappropriate here